# iframe Fade Out/In with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need an iframe to fade out the old page and then fade in with the new page when the user clicks one of the various link and I can’t get the code to work. Just wondering if you can see where I went wrong.

```
<div id="menubar1">
    <a href="link1" target="iframe1"> link 1 </a>
    <a href="link 2" target="iframe1"> link 2 </a>
    <a href="link 3" target="iframe1"> link 3 </a>
    <a href="link 4" target="iframe1"> link 4 </a>
</div>

<iframe id="iframe1" name="iframe1" src="homepage.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<script>
      $("#menubar1 a").click(function() {
          $("#iframe1").FadeOut("slow");
          $("#iframe1").FadeIn("slow");
       });
</script>
```

Comment: first change the src attribute of the iFrame and then use the .FadeIn() .

Comment: What's not happening for you? There's nowhere in your code that tells the iframe to change src. Just fade in and out. Is that specifically the issue? That you see no fade in or out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This way should work.

```
  $("#menubar1 a").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var src = $(this).attr('href');

      $('#iframe1').fadeOut(1000,function(){
          $('#iframe1').attr('src',src );
          $('#iframe1').fadeIn(1000);
      });
  });
```

You can now remove the target attribute since we've handled it via jQuery.

```
<a href="link1"> link 1 </a>
```

---

I've tested this on jsfiddle to see how it works. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/ZnMTK/)

Then I noticed the `iframe` is blinking after the content is fully loaded. So I added a `load()` function to fix the blinking and it's working very well. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/ZnMTK/1/)

```
  $("#menubar1 a").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var src = $(this).attr('href');

      $('#iframe1').fadeOut(1000,function(){
          $('#iframe1').attr('src',src ).load(function(){
              $(this).fadeIn(1000);    
          });
      });

 });
```

Comment: this one is correct although you may want to call `e.preventDefault()`  before `return false;`

Comment: Thanks @lincolnk. I've tried it on jsfiddle and `return false` works okay. But think `e.preventDefault()` is the best way to prevent default action rather than abusing the return operator. :D

Answer (score -2):

Simply a syntax error with the capitalization of .fadeOut (you wrote .FadeOut).

```
$("#menubar1 a").click(function() {
     $("#iframe1").fadeOut("slow");
     $("#iframe1").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Although I recommend you do the following:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="menubar1">
    <a href="#" id="link1"> link 1 </a>
    <a href="#" id="link 2"> link 2 </a>
    <a href="#" id="link 3"> link 3 </a>
    <a href="#" id="link 4"> link 4 </a>
</div>

<iframe id="iframe1" name="iframe1" src="homepage.html" frameborder="0" >
</iframe>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#menubar1 a").click(function() {
    var linkId = this.id; // id of clicked a element
    $("#iframe1").fadeOut("slow", function() {; // fade out iframe
        document.getElementById("iframe1").src = linkId; // on completion of fade out - change iframe src attribute
        $("#iframe1").fadeIn("slow"); //fade in iframe
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This way the contents of your iframe will not change before the fadeOut.

Comment: have to wait for fadeOut to finish before doing next steps

Comment: I can't seem to comment on any other post - but I believe the answer given by Mark S won't work due to the fact that clicking the links will load the page indicated in the href.

Comment: lincolnk, you might want to change your comment. Unless I am wrong. Also If you look at my post now, you will see that my suggested method of doing this, includes a wait until the fadeOut function has completed.

Comment: @aruuu you need to call in `fadeIn()` during the `fadeOut()` callback. currently you are going to suffer the same issue as @codeSpy. also setting the iframe src attribute to a.id isn't going to do anything useful.

Comment: @lincolnk If you read the html that I have also changed, you will see that the id of the a elements are the url that was previously in href. If you just use the href in the a elements you will be redirected to that page when they are clicked. I will change the fadeIn now - good point, thanks.